# How to convert YOLO annotations (.txt) to PASCAL VOC (.xml)?

Tags: computer-vision, label, object-detection, yolo

I have built a dataset to train YOLOv4 and I have all the labels in YOLO format (I used LabelImg). Now I want to train SSD with the same dataset and therefore I need the labels in the PASCAL VOC format. I have seen some ways to do the opposite conversion (voc to yolo) but not the one I am looking for. Since I have thousands of images I want to find a way to automate this whole procedure without having to go through each image/label one by one.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I have had the same problem. I wrote a script that will do this conversion for you. You can find a link to the code here: https://github.com/JPM-Tech/Object-Detection/tree/main/Scripts/converters/convert-yolo-to-xml.py. This is a link to some docs that were written on how to use it: https://github.com/JPM-Tech/Object-Detection/tree/main/Scripts/converters#convert-yolo-to-xml. Hopefully this helps you as much as it has helped me.

Answer (score 6):

My classmates and I have created a python package called PyLabel to help others with this task and other labelling tasks. You can see an example in this notebook https://github.com/pylabel-project/samples/blob/main/yolo2coco.ipynb.

The general solution is the same as what the others have mentioned above but the code encapsulated in this package so you only have to right minimal code. For example:

```
!pip install pylabel
from pylabel import importer
dataset = importer.ImportYoloV5(path=path_to_annotations)
dataset.export.ExportToVoc(dataset)
```

You can find the source code that is used behind the scenes here https://github.com/pylabel-project/pylabel/tree/main/pylabel

Comment: Thanks this works. Also dataset.export.ExportToVoc(dataset) should be dataset.export.ExportToVoc(export_dir)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script for creating an XML, when the relevant information is provided i.e the variables at the start of the script.

```py
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from PIL import Image
import os

image_path = "" # provide image path
anno_folder = "" # provide .XML folder path
filename = "" # provide image name
#Read each bounding box as a list of dictionary and append it in the list for each file
All_bboxes = "[{"xmin":1433,"xmax":1503,"ymin":1570,"ymax":1700,"skuLabel":"bus"}]" 


img = np.array(Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB'))

annotation = ET.Element('annotation')
ET.SubElement(annotation, 'folder').text = str(anno_folder)
ET.SubElement(annotation, 'filename').text = str(filename)
ET.SubElement(annotation, 'path').text = str(filename)

source = ET.SubElement(annotation, 'source')
ET.SubElement(source, 'database').text = 'Unknown'

size = ET.SubElement(annotation, 'size')
ET.SubElement(size, 'width').text = str (img.shape[1])
ET.SubElement(size, 'height').text = str(img.shape[0])
ET.SubElement(size, 'depth').text = str(img.shape[2])

ET.SubElement(annotation, 'segmented').text = '0'

for item in All_bboxes:
    label = item['Label']
    xmax = item['xmax']
    xmin = item['xmin']
    ymin = item['ymin']
    ymax = item['ymax']

    object = ET.SubElement(annotation, 'object')
    ET.SubElement(object, 'name').text = label
    ET.SubElement(object, 'pose').text = 'Unspecified'
    ET.SubElement(object, 'truncated').text = '0'
    ET.SubElement(object, 'difficult').text = '0'

    bndbox = ET.SubElement(object, 'bndbox')
    ET.SubElement(bndbox, 'xmin').text = str(xmin)
    ET.SubElement(bndbox, 'ymin').text = str(ymin)
    ET.SubElement(bndbox, 'xmax').text = str(xmax)
    ET.SubElement(bndbox, 'ymax').text = str(ymax)

tree = ET.ElementTree(annotation)
xml_file_name = os.path.join(anno_folder, f'{filename.split('.')[0]}.xml')
tree.write(xml_file_name)
```

In Yolo format, you have `x y width height` while in PASCAL VOC you have `xmin ymin xmax ymax`. SO you have to convert that while loading them into the `All_bboxes`. [This](https://github.com/git-hamza/Yolo_V4/blob/b707f901adb7b87c3978e76fdcac9df520d153cc/data/xml_to_txt/transformer.py#L36) function converts .xml format to .txt so it can help you with conversion of co-ordinates.

P.S. You can loops over the above code to make it work for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool

```
pip install pascal-voc
```

```
from pascal import annotation_from_yolo
from pascal.utils import save_xml

label_map = {
    0: "person",
    1: "dog"
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ann = annotation_from_yolo(
        "000001.txt",
        label_map=label_map,
        img_w=353,
        img_h=500)
    
    xml = ann.to_xml()
    save_xml("000001.xml", xml)
```